# CATransaction (still) Not Animating

Tags: iphone, core-animation

I have a problem very similar to this one :

[CATransaction Not Animating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/805502/catransaction-not-animating)

I'm just trying to animate a view layer using CATransaction. My problem is that the transform is applied to the view immediatly.

I tried to perform the animation using performSelector:withObject:afterDelay: without success.

Here is my code :

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

 view = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(100, 100, 100, 100)] autorelease];
 view.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
 [self.view addSubview:view];

 [self performSelector:@selector(animateView) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.1];
}

-(void) animateView {
 [CATransaction begin];
 [CATransaction setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:3.0f] forKey:kCATransactionAnimationDuration];
    CALayer *layer = view.layer;
    layer.position = CGPointMake(20, 
         300);
    CATransform3D transform = CATransform3DMakeScale(2.0f, 2.0f, 1.0f);
    transform = CATransform3DRotate(transform, acos(-1.0f)*1.5f, 1.5f, 1.5f, 1.5f);
    layer.transform = transform;
    [CATransaction commit];
}
```

Does anybody knows what is going wrong ?

Thanks, Vincent.

Comment: Did you try explicitly setting disableActions to off? I know implicit transactions are disabled on the iPhone, so it's possible that CATransaction simply defaults to disabled.

BTW, you can use `[CATransaction setAnimationDuration:0.3]` instead of `-setValue:forKey:`.

Comment: I down-voted this simply because the exact question you link to has the answer, which it looks like you did not try in your example code.

Comment: It doesn't address the problem of how to actually animate using a CATransaction, but I agree that using UIView animations is the "nicer" solution. Also note that it makes more sense to animate in viewWillAppear/viewDidAppear, not viewDidLoad - views can be loaded a long time before they're displayed.

Comment: Ok sorry for this, in fact in was thinking UIView animation block was only working for animating the view properties, not the layer properties.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

when animating a view's backing layer, you need to be inside a `UIView` animation block, not just a `CATransaction`:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:NULL];
// ... your animation code
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Answer (score 0):

or you could use CAAnimationGroup and group the scale and rotation animations like this..

```
CAAnimationGroup *aniGroup = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
// setup aniGroup properties

CABasicAnimation *scaleAnimation = [CABasicAnimation defaultValueForKey:@"transform.scale"];
scaleAnimation.fromValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0];
scaleAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:1.0];
// setup scaleAnimation properties

CABasicAnimation *rotateAnimation = [CABasicAnimation defaultValueForKey:@"transform.rotate"];
// setup rotateAnimation properties
// ....

aniGroup.animations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:rotateAnimation, scaleAnimation, nil];

[self.layer layoutIfNeeded];
[self.layer addAnimation:aniGroup forKey:@"myAnimation"];
```

Something like that.... Might not be exactly copy, paste, and build-able. ;)

Hope this helps!